# Zombie movie wherein a man discovers an unfamiliar word

Tags: story-identification, movie

A friend told me about this a while back. The movie was supposedly named *The Young Tree* or something similar.

- A guy is reading a children's book in a library and comes across an unfamiliar word. He proceeds to look it up in a dictionary. Everyone in the library then starts to stare at him.
- In the street, people start staring at the man, too. It turns out that they are all zombies, and he is (one of) the last human(s) left.
- The movie ends with the man failing to outrun his assailants and being initiated as a zombie.

I'd expect it to be an early 2000s movie in the English language, but who knows?